# Why `is_constructible<function<int(int)>, int(*)(int,int)>::value` is true under VC2015RC

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, type-traits, std-function

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   static_assert(is_constructible<function<int(int)>, int(*)(int,int)>::value, "error");
}
```

The code doesn't compile with GCC and Clang, but passed with Visual C++ 2015 RC.

Is this standard compliant behavior or just a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`std::function`'s constructor used to accept everything under the sun (it was a `template<class F> function(F f)`).

Then it got constrained in the standard (by [LWG issue 2132](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2132)), but implementing that constraint requires expression SFINAE, which [Microsoft's compiler doesn't yet support](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2015/04/29/c-11-14-17-features-in-vs-2015-rc.aspx).

Comment: Geeee...another expression SFINAE issue. But I still have the question, from the C++ standard perspective, is this behavior correct? Or it's valid in C++11 and invalid in C++14?

Comment: @Windoze Under the C++11 standard as published, passing something that's not Callable for the given signature breaks a *Requires* clause, which is UB, so any answer is correct. In C++14, that `is_constructible` should be false.

Comment: Is it UB already when instantiated with the type or UB only when the constructor call is actually evaluated?

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb I think instantiation is sufficient. [res.on.functions]/2, bullet 2.3.

Comment: @windoze I think `std::result_of` both works, and is sfinae friendly (if not expression sfinae), in 2015 (even 2013), so expression sfinae is not even an excuse here.

Comment: @Yakk No, `result_of` isn't SFINAE friendly either in MSVC.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 has the more-constrained C++14 `std::function` and `std::result_of`, see *Functional-ish Fixes* on [STL Fixes In VS 2015 Update 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/04/14/stl-fixes-in-vs-2015-update-2/)