# Overloading a function that takes a std::function with a different function signature results in compiler error

Tags: templates, c++11, overloading

I came across this compiler/language issue while working on a callback system.  I'm using Visual Studio 2012.  If I write:

```
// Works
template<typename T>
class C
{
};
C<void(int)>        a1;
C<void(int, int)>   a2;
void Good(C<void(int)>)         { }
void Good(C<void(int, int)>)    { }

void main()
{
    Good(a1);
    Good(a2);
}
```

it compiles cleanly and I verified in the debugger that the correct overloads are being called.

However, if I write:

```
void Foo(std::function<void(int)> fn)   { }
void Foo(std::function<void(int, int)> fn)  { } //<--- breaks compilation
void Bar(int a) { }

void main()
{
    Foo(Bar);
}
```

I get the following:

```
>c:\dev\newtech2\src\game.cpp(389): error C2668: 'Foo' : ambiguous call to overloaded function
>          c:\dev\newtech2\src\game.cpp(380): could be 'void Foo(std::function<_Fty>)'
>          with
>          [
>              _Fty=void (int,int)
>          ]
>          c:\dev\newtech2\src\game.cpp(379): or       'void Foo(std::function<_Fty>)'
>          with
>          [
>              _Fty=void (int)
>          ]
>          while trying to match the argument list '(overloaded-function)'
```

The compiler clearly knows that the two functions have different signatures due to the different template parameters, and it was able to distinguish the two in the previous example using my own template class.  So is this a compiler/STL bug or some limitation in how std::function() works?  Not a show-stopper but does limit one type of callback interface I wanted to provide.

Comment: In the example that works, the argument type matches that of the parameter exactly. In the one that does not work, this is not true.

Comment: This is [LWG 2132](http://cplusplus.github.io/LWG/lwg-defects.html#2132). Bug in the standard that has been fixed, but VS can't implement the fix because the fix requires expression SFINAE to implement, and VS still doesn't have that.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498829/why-is-constructiblefunctionintint-intint-intvalue-is-true-under

Comment: @t.c. they did a partial fix in VS2015

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 has the more-constrained C++14 `std::function`, see *Functional-ish Fixes* on [STL Fixes In VS 2015 Update 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/04/14/stl-fixes-in-vs-2015-update-2/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the example that works, types of the arguments `a1` and `a2` match exactly the corresponding parameter types of the two `Good` overloads. This is not true to the second example. The selected constructor of `std::function` is a function template, and has little to do with the function signature you supplied whatsoever. That is, in the eye of the compiler, to (try to) convert `Bar` to `std::function<void(int)>` is no better than to convert it to `std::function<void(int, int)>`, despite the fact that choosing the second will ultimately lead to a compiler error (the compiler cannot foresee this anyway). One way to remedy the situation is to explicitly cast the argument `Bar` to the appropriate `std::function` type, or to make a convenient converter wrapper yourself to automate this procedure.