# Erroneous behaviour in MSVC when constructing a std::tuple

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-c++, compiler-errors, c++14

I recently encountered (at least I think it is) erroneous behaviour in MSVC++ 2015 (oh, what news...) when trying to compile the following code (obiously simplified):

```
#include <tuple>
#include <functional>

template<typename T>
using Func = std::function<void(T)>;

template<class...Ts>
class Foo
{
public:
    using Tuples = std::tuple<Func<Ts>...>;
    Foo(Tuples arg)
        : m_tuples(arg)
    {}
private:
    Tuples m_tuples;
};

struct Bar
{};

int main() {
    Foo<Bar> foo{std::make_tuple([](Bar) {})};
    return 0;
}
```

It works just fine with clang and gcc (both new and older versions with c++14 support) but in MSVC++2015 it fails to compile with a very interesting error message:

```
type_traits(1494): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'
type_traits(1494): note: With the following template arguments:
type_traits(1494): note: '_Callable=std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>> &'
type_traits(1494): note: '_Types={Bar}'
```

The first strange behaviour becomes apparent here: Why does the compiler try to use the tuple as a function object? Further up in the stack it becomes clear:
It erroneously instantiates the element constructor

```
template< class... UTypes >
explicit constexpr tuple( UTypes&&... args );
```

instead of using the default one which would exhibit correct behaviour - it even appears that an additional SFINAE check in MSVC's std implementation fails to catch this:

```
_Tuple_enable<tuple<tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>> &>, tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>
```

That should obviously lead to a removal of this constructor from the overload set, since it just boils down to a check if `tuple<tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>> &>` is convertible to `tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>` (AFAIK this conversion doesn't exist). I fail to understand why it wouldn't just use the default copy constructor - or is my interpretation of the standard wrong?

Since clang and gcc both manage to compile this code with correct behaviour, my question is now: Is this a bug with Microsoft's std implementation or a compiler bug? For reference, changing the constructor to `Foo(const Tuples& arg)` forces MSVC to use the right tuple constructor (and the code compiles fine), whereas both alternatives `Foo(Tuples&& arg)` and `Foo(Tuples& arg)` use the erroneous element constructor as well.

The full error log is below:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TestProject, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  test.cpp
1>g:\misc\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(1494): error C2893: Failed to specialize function template 'unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)'
1>  g:\misc\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(1494): note: With the following template arguments:
1>  g:\misc\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(1494): note: '_Callable=std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>> &'
1>  g:\misc\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(1494): note: '_Types={Bar}'
1>  g:\misc\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\functional(210): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Invoke_ret<_Rx,_Callable&,_Ty>(std::_Forced<_Rx,true>,_Callable &,_Ty &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Rx=void,
1>              _Callable=_Decayed,
1>              _Ty=Bar
1>          ]
1>  g:\misc\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\functional(208): note: while compiling class template member function 'void std::_Func_impl<_Decayed,_Alloc,_Ret,Bar>::_Do_call(Bar &&)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<int>,
1>              _Ret=void
1>          ]
1>  g:\misc\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\functional(136): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Func_impl<_Decayed,_Alloc,_Ret,Bar>' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<int>,
1>              _Ret=void
1>          ]
1>  g:\misc\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\functional(339): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'std::_Is_large<_Myimpl>' being compiled
1>  g:\misc\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\functional(318): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,Bar>::_Reset_alloc<_Ty,std::allocator<int>>(_Fx &&,const _Alloc &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void,
1>              _Ty=std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>,
1>              _Fx=std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<int>
1>          ]
1>  g:\misc\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\functional(318): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,Bar>::_Reset_alloc<_Ty,std::allocator<int>>(_Fx &&,const _Alloc &)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void,
1>              _Ty=std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>,
1>              _Fx=std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>,
1>              _Alloc=std::allocator<int>
1>          ]
1>  g:\misc\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\functional(484): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,Bar>::_Reset<std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void,
1>              _Fx=std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>
1>          ]
1>  g:\misc\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\functional(484): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'void std::_Func_class<_Ret,Bar>::_Reset<std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>>(_Fx &&)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Ret=void,
1>              _Fx=std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>
1>          ]
1>  g:\misc\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\tuple(75): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<void (Bar)>::function<std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>>(_Fx)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fx=std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>
1>          ]
1>  g:\misc\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\tuple(75): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::function<void (Bar)>::function<std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>>(_Fx)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Fx=std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>
1>          ]
1>  g:\misc\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\tuple(233): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tuple_val<_This>::_Tuple_val<std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>&>(_Other)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _This=std::function<void (Bar)>,
1>              _Other=std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>> &
1>          ]
1>  g:\misc\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\tuple(233): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::_Tuple_val<_This>::_Tuple_val<std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>&>(_Other)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _This=std::function<void (Bar)>,
1>              _Other=std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>> &
1>          ]
1>  test.cpp(115): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>::tuple<std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>&,,std::_Tuple_enable<std::tuple<>,std::tuple<>>::type>(_This2)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _This2=std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>> &
1>          ]
1>  test.cpp(115): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>::tuple<std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>&,,std::_Tuple_enable<std::tuple<>,std::tuple<>>::type>(_This2)' being compiled
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _This2=std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>> &
1>          ]
1>  test.cpp(113): note: while compiling class template member function 'Foo<Bar>::Foo(std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>)'
1>  test.cpp(134): note: see reference to function template instantiation 'Foo<Bar>::Foo(std::tuple<std::function<void (Bar)>>)' being compiled
1>  test.cpp(134): note: see reference to class template instantiation 'Foo<Bar>' being compiled
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: "(AFAIK this conversion doesn't exist)" [it existed in C++11, because `std::function`s used to be convertible from everything under the sun.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30498829/why-is-constructiblefunctionintint-intint-intvalue-is-true-under) Fixing that requires expression SFINAE, which MSVC doesn't have.

Comment: Thanks, interesting to know. There still remains the question why it even tries to instantiate the element constructor and not the copy constructor (shouldn't the latter be more specialized in this case?)

Comment: It's a better match than the copy constructor, since (after template argument deduction) it binds a `tuple<...>&` to a non-`const` lvalue, rather than a `const tuple<...> &`.

Comment: Visual Studio 2015 Update 2 has the more-constrained C++14 `std::function`, see *Functional-ish Fixes* on [STL Fixes In VS 2015 Update 2](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2016/04/14/stl-fixes-in-vs-2015-update-2/)

Comment: VS2015 Update 3 compiles above code without a problem